# Issue with psycopg2 SSL Support when Converting Kivy App to APK

Tags: python, ssl, kivy, psycopg2, python-for-android

I've developed a Python Kivy app that runs fine on Windows. To convert it into an APK file for mobile devices, I'm using python-for-android with a GitHub workflow. However, attempting to launch the app on a mobile device results in a crash after a few seconds. Upon inspecting the logs with logcat, I discovered the following error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: sslmode value "verify full" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in.

It appears that the psycopg2 package lacks SSL support. Here are the provided requirements during the building process:

--requirements

```
python3==3.7.6
hostpython3==3.7.6
android
openssl,pyopenssl
httplib2,postgres
setuptools
Cython==0.29.10
sdl2_ttf==2.0.15
pillow
certifi
typing
typing_extensions
sh
pyjnius
backports.zoneinfo
psycopg2==2.9.5
kivy==2.0.0
kivymd==1.0.1
```

I tried to add openssl, pyopenssl, httplib2 and certify to the requirements. Also I added sudo apt-get install libssl-dev to the github workflow. It didn't resolve the problem.

Before I create the apk I install the following on the Ubuntu machine:

```
        run: |
          [[ $- == *i* ]] && stty -ixon
          sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python3-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-8-jdk unzip ant ccache autoconf libtool libssl-dev
          sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
          sudo apt-get install openssl
          sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
          python3 -m pip install cython
          python3 -m pip install Cython==0.29.10
          python3 -m pip install kivy==2.0.0
          python3 -m pip install postgres
          python3 -m pip install psycopg2==2.9.5
          python3 -m pip install python-for-android
        shell: bash
```

Comment: 1) The error message is coming from the `libpq` version used with `psycopg2` .  2) How did you install `psycopg2`? 3) Do you have the dev libraries installed?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I added the part where I installed the required packages before I create the apk.

Comment: 1) Where there any errors when `python3 -m pip install psycopg2==2.9.5`? 2) What does `ldd <psycopg executable> show a link to `libssl.so`? In my case the executable is `_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu` 3) Was the Postgres server built with SSL support?

Comment: There were no errors with pip install psycopg2. The postgres server has definetly SSL support. I am even able to connect to the database with the ubuntu machine with psql command. Could it be due to the python-for-android recipe for psycopg2? The documentary says if i use a requirement where there is an existing recipe on p4a, it will use the recipe. It seems to me that the psycopg2 recipe installs psycopg2 without SSL support. https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes/psycopg2/__init__.py

Comment: Yeah looks that way to me. That would be something you need to discuss with the python-for-android folks.